# How to choose pixel values according to each land cover class?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcgis-desktop, spatial-analyst, spatial-statistics, erdas-imagine

I would like to do following steps using two types of images (precpitation and Land cover image):

1. select pixel values of precipitation image within each land cover classes
2. calculate total amount of precipitation of each land cover classes

Could you please tell me the tools I use and the steps I need to follow in ArcGIS, ENVI, or ERDAS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In ArcGIS use the [zonal statistics](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//009z000000w7000000) tool.